# Differentiable functions on closed and open sets in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, complex-analysis

Is there a difference between functions holomorphic (on open sets $\Omega$) and functions that have derivatives everywhere on $\mathcal{Cl}(\Omega)$ (their closure in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$, more precisely in some algebra on $\mathbb{C}$)?

For holomorphic functions:
$$ \exists \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z- z_0}, \; \forall z_0 \in \Omega$$
I am naively interpreting this as a sequence of complex numbers $g(z_n)$ that converge to $f'(z_0)$ for any path $z_n \to z_0$ (this is done via a sequence of algebraic operations). But if $f$ is an algebraic function, is this not the same as restriction to some subalgebra? Then its closure would be the entire algebra on $\mathbb{C}$?

I might be missing something vital here in this naive interpretation (and I assume it is due to my improper grasp of a few elementary notions). Examples or counter-examples would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a difference between functions holomorphic (on open sets $\Omega$) and functions that have derivatives everywhere on $\overline{\Omega}$?

Yes. The function $f(z)=\sqrt{1+z}$ is holomorphic in $\Omega=\{z:|z|<1\}$ but does not have a derivative at $-1$, which is an element of $\overline{\Omega}$.

Comment: Yes, I see now. This is due to translation of $\sqrt{z}$ which has a branch cut on the negative reals (by choice of principal value). Also, the $n$-th roots appear as an algebraic closure themselves (as a generalized continued fraction - which trivially terminates for perfect powers of $n$)... The appearance of branch cuts (as a consequence of a closure) separates open sets. This should lead in to the topological theory of Riemann surfaces. I see there is still a lot I have to learn.